# How to get list of folders/files which are not part of My Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to query a google drive with parent filter. There are some folders and files which are not linked to My Drive but are available from All Items view. [My own files and not files shared with me]

Is there a query that i can use to get only these folders and files. When i observe the parent attribute for these items, i see that they are empty. Tried using query like ['' in parent] etc but didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it to fetch an example of a file that **is** in "My Drive" and one that is not. Then compare the returned File resource to see if there is a distinguishing feature that you can query or filter on.